# Running npm as a script "npm run protractor" throw console errors after test execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, protractor, e2e-testing

We recently decided to control easy installation of protractor on local machines (by specifying it in package.json) instead of installing individually with -g flag. So addition is something like this

```
"scripts": {
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js --directConnect"
}
```

After that when I try to execute protractor using
npm run protractor

It gives following console error after running tests.

***npm ERR! Failed at the @ protractor script 'sudo protractor protractor.config.js --directConnect'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.***
....
....

Running protractor using following command works fine.

```
node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor.config.js --directConnect
```

Also it works ok if protractor is installed as global package and run as below

```
protractor protractor.config.js --directConnect
```

Only problem that running it as scripts always gives errors after tests run is finished.

Comment: it is mentioned in the command, you have to give sudo permissions to run commands from npm script

Answer (score 0):

change you script:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "protractor protractor.config.js --directConnect"
}
```

and then use `npm test` to give a try

Comment: It should work with `npm run protractor` script as well, sudo permissions have to be given.

Comment: Thanks Howard. It seems to work better but I get in the end
npm ERR! Test failed. See above for more details

I don't get this error still when running global protractor or by using
node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor.config.js --directConnect

@Ram I am using windows so how would I give sudo permissions there?

Comment: I would not like to launch a command prompt with administrator privileges. It would be nice if it just works as a global protractor version.

Comment: @ZiaRizwan any more details? For example, info from npm debug log?

Comment: There isn't really more information in logs I am afraid :/ Its really easily reproducible as I mentioned in original post. I googled earlier and found similar posts where people resolved issue simply by running/installing protractor as global package (which I would not intend to do). This is a known issue for a while I suppose and I am interested to find a reason and a possible fix :)